# mi código php no se ejecuta

Tags: php, html

Estoy tratando de hacer una página con html y php, sin embargo el código php no ejecuta, únicamente el html, alguien sabes a que se debe?? si es así y me pueden auxiliar se los agradeceré bastante!

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first PHP page</h1>

<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi.. the official language of the site is spanish. If spanish is your first language, please translate it.

Comment: Hay muchas razones por la cual no se pueda, las principales que se me ocurren son: ¿Si tienes un servidor de PHP ejecutando en tu máquina? ¿Si guardaste tu archivo con extensión .php?

Comment: gracias, si está como .php y si se está ejecutando el servidor, de hecho para descartar situaciones ya lo corrí en servidores diferentes y nada

Comment: Tu código  funciona bien, ya lo corrí en mi propio servidor sin problemas.para pruebas si estas en entorno Windows te sugiero usar XAMPP.

Comment: @Lixus pregunta si ese servidor en particular tiene PHP corriendo... suena a que no...

Comment: @gbianchi  te agrdezco su tiempo, como puedo checar lo del servidor con php corriendo?? la verdad soy novatisimo en esto y bueno, estoy moviendole.

Comment: Juanpa, bienvenido a [so.en]. Por favor, edita tu pregunta y cuida que seguir esta guía [ask]. De ser posible, incluye un __[mcve]]__.

Comment: Que servidor web estas utilizando?

Comment: @JorgeArturoJuarez estoy trabajando con appserv

Comment: si estas ingresando desde localhost/tuarchivo.php?

Comment: @JorgeArturoJuarez estoy ingresando así file:///C:/AppServ/www/hello world/n.php

Comment: ese es el problema, solamente estas abriendo tu archivo como si no tuvieras servidor, tienes que llamarlo, primero quitale el espacio al directorio 'hello world' luego entra desde localhost/helloworld/n.php

Comment: @JorgeArturoJuarez muchas gracias estimado, ya quedo